# How to get ubuntu 18.04 to talk to SIM card programmer

Tags: system-installation

1) Running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, codename:bionic. Ubuntu is the only OS on the laptop
2) when pcsc_scan is run, Smart Reader 0, card state: Card inserted and ATR return. But Reader 1 and Reader 2, Card state: card removed 
3) Downloaded pysim-master.zip in download directory. run sudo apt install pysim-master. error Unable to locate package pysim-master
4) Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct 7 2019, 17:39:04) installed
5) Run sudo apt install pcsc-tools, it shows pcsc-tools is already the newest version (1.5.2.2)
6) But when run pcsc-tools, it states command not found
7) when run sudo apt-get install pcscd pcsc-tools libccid libpcsclite-dev python-pyscard, it shows libccid (1.4.29-1), pcsc-tools (1.5.2.2) and pcscd (1.8.23-1) already newest version
8) when run sudo apt install git clone git://git.osmocom.org/pysim pysim, errors i)unable to locate package git://git.osmocom.org, ii) cant find any package by glob 'git://git.osmocom.org', iii) can't find any package by regex 'git://git.osmocom.org', iv) unable to locate package pysim
9) when run sudo apt install http://git.osmocom.org/osmo-sim-auth, error ii) cant find any package by glob 'http://git.osmocom.org', iii) can't find any package by regex 'http://git.osmocom.org'

BUT, I am able to access the git website of http://git.osmocom.org/pysim and http://git.osmocom.org/osmo-sim-auth on firefox web browser

Comment: Hi K7AAY, many thanks for your response and advice. The ubuntu is currently located on C drive Program Files-?WIndowsApps and not in dual boot configuration.  Is that the reason of some missing functionalities due to the windows/ubuntu sitting on the same memory space. So it seems that 1) try a dual boot configuration mode or 2) install the unbuntu on a separate drive for clean installtion. Please  advise

Comment: Dual Boot will be clean. That's my advice.

Comment: Thanks K7AAY for your help. will try.

Comment: Hi K7AAY, I used a different PC with just Unbuntu installed (no windows), I have the same problem from the very beginning. I am not able to run pc to smart card link test with same error message                         
 $ sudo apt install pcsc-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pcsc-tools      I thought the pcsc_tools is prte-installed on Ubuntu , If not, even I can download it, where to install. This is risky by manually manipulate the files

Comment: Hi K7AAY, I used a different PC with just Unbuntu installed (no windows), I have the same problem from the very beginning. I am not able to run pc to smart card link test with same error message                         
 $ sudo apt install pcsc-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pcsc-tools

Comment: I thought the pcsc_tools is prte-installed on Ubuntu , If not, even I can download it, where to install. This is risky by manually manipulate the files...   Sorry for formatting.I can not break them into separate lines

Comment: 1) If you reply in the question by clicking [edit] you have formatting capability. 2) If you move a comment into the question, make sure to delete the comment by clicking Delete at the end of the comment. 3) Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .   4) _pcsc-tools_ (1.5.2-2) and _pcscd (1.8.23-1)_ require universe be enabled. Is it? Please respond using [edit].

Comment: Hi K7AAY. I have now managed to download and install the pcsc-tool (1.5.2.2). But when I run pcsc_scan, it still does not seem to connect between the ubuntu and the smart card reader (see below)
$pscs_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V1.5.2 © 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau ludovic.rousseau@free.fr
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available

Comment: Sorry I am still not able to format, Not familar how to respond your comment, I only can use "add comment" , a novice user. I clicked the edit in your comment, but does not give me a format capability.. Sorry

Comment: Hi K7AAY. latest update. I installed pcscd and libccid, pcsc scan seems to work and able to read the sim card. But strange saying read1 and reader 2 card removed. I will play with it a bit more and see if I can reprogram some parameters. WIll  keep you post how I get on end of next week. In the meantime, any further advice and tips to program SIM card K and opco values are welcome

Comment: Hi K7AAY, I am not having much with SIM programming on ubuntu. If you or anybody else have good instruction, please can i have a copy. 1) i tried to download python (python-master)but it is in zip format and not tar.gz in download folder. When excute python-master on ubuntu, it says cant locate the file. 2) ten follow python wiki instruction, install python3, 2) install sudo apt install git clone git://git.osmocom.org/pysim.pysim, then errors - unable to locate package clone, unable to locate package git://git.osmocom.org etc....... Appreciate helps

Comment: Your findings should (always) be added to your question, to demonstrate what you tried and show what did not work. Please click [edit] to do so.